# Get unrotated coordinates from a rotated div

Tags: javascript

I have a div that is getting rotated. I actually want to know it's orginal left and top coordinates before it was rotated.

I've been looking at different formulas but i think i need someone to help me a bit.

Thanks,

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="test" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:yellow;tranform:rotate(45deg);transform-orgin:top left">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

As a formula, i found this one.

```
function rotatedPosition(pLeft, pTop, oLeft, oTop, angle){
    // 1
    var x = pLeft - oLeft;
    var y = pTop - oTop;

    // 2
    var xRot = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
    var yRot = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);

    // 3
    var pLeftRot = xRot + oLeft;
    var pTopRot = yRot + oTop

    return {left: pLeftRot, top: pTopRot};
}
```

This will calculate the rotated coordinates. I tried to modifiy it so that it would calculate the original coordinates in stead of the rotated coordinates. But that kind of math is to long ago for me.

It is using a css transfrom: rotate(45deg); tranform-origin: top left;. I'm getting this div already rotated so i don't know it's unrotated coordinates. in the end i need to get the top and left position of the div as it would appear unrotated.

Comment: Please share your code, and explain what you've already tried. How is the `<div>` being rotated, for example.

Comment: Are you using CSS-rotate method? How are you rotating? What `[left, top]` values are you getting? Why are they wrong? What do you need to accomplish?

Answer (score -2):

Ok, that's it... store the top and left values before calling rotatedPosition function.
By the way, I would recommend you to use **let** and **const** instead of **var** within the function body. That way those identifiers will only exist in there.

```
<html>
 <script>
    var original_Top = -1, original_Left = -1;
    function rotatedPosition(pLeft, pTop, oLeft, oTop, angle){
      original_Top = pTop;
      original_Left = pLeft;
      // 1
      let x = pLeft - oLeft;
      let y = pTop - oTop;

      // 2
      let xRot = x * Math.cos(angle) - y * Math.sin(angle);
      let yRot = x * Math.sin(angle) + y * Math.cos(angle);

      // 3
      let pLeftRot = xRot + oLeft;
      let pTopRot = yRot + oTop

      return {left: pLeftRot, top: pTopRot};
 }
 </script>
 <body>
  <div id="test" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:yellow">
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I don't know where you call the rotatedPosition function. This is only an idea, you also can store these values calling another function.